# In SQL, which db platforms support the count(8) syntax?

Tags: sql

I have seen count(8) produce the same functionality as count(*) on REDShift. Are they equivalent and what other platforms use them (I want my ansi SQL code be portable)

Comment: `COUNT` with a constant value return the number of rows in every DB I know, using 8 instead of 1 or * is probably just to make someone wonder why 8 is used?

Comment: @Serpiton - because it's lower-case `*` on some keyboards, and someone mis-hit the shift key?

Comment: @Serpiton */8 are the same key? They only have to release the shift? Same reason I often do top 8 * instead of top 10 *?

Comment: @Liath I'm in Italy, in my keyboard is 8/( I've not thought of the US keyboard layout

Comment: The only sensible constant for `count()` is `42` (SCNR)

Comment: @Serpiton not 100% sure on US but UK it's definitely the same key

Comment: @Liath: Not 100% sure of UK, but in US and Canada definitely the same key.